# htaccess rewrite url path with differnet file access

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ stateName.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ stateCounty.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ statelocality.php [L]
```

i want output like this

```
 http://yourdomain.com/alabama/           /* RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ stateName.php [L] */
 http://yourdomain.com/autuga-county-alabama/  /* RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ stateCounty.php [L] */
 http://yourdomain.com/alexander-city-alabama/ /* RewriteRule ^([a-z~&A-Z0-9_-]+)/$ statelocality.php [L] */
```

but above .htacces rewrite code only accessing stateName.php. any suggestion how can i do. thanks in advance

Comment: You can not use the exact same pattern multiple times, and expect that to give different results.

Comment: any solution for me ?

Comment: Not until you define a _solvable_ problem to begin with. What you are currently asking for, simply does not make sense. Say I request `http://yourdomain.com/foobar/` - can _you_ tell, whether I meant `foobar` to be a state, county or locality? No? Then how would you expect your server to make that differentiation, at this point?

Comment: ok i got your point

Answer (score 0):

With `-county-` or `-city-` always in the links you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z\d_-]+-county-[a-z\d_-]+/?$ stateCounty.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-z\d_-]+-city-[a-z\d_-]+/?$ statelocality.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-z\d_-]+/$ stateName.php [NC,L]
```

you can even make variations:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z\d_-]+-(?:city|locality|other)-[a-z\d_-]+/?$ statelocality.php [NC,L]
```

which works the same way with the 3 links:

```
http://yourdomain.com/alexander-city-alabama/
http://yourdomain.com/alexander-locality-alabama/
http://yourdomain.com/alexander-other-alabama/
```